# Windows 8 native look in .net 4 wpf ribbons

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, windows-8, ribbon

I am developing an application that uses wpf ribbons.

One of the most important requirements is .net 4 support (because of Windows XP).

Here is the problem. Ribbons for .net 4 don't have Windows 8 style. I checked .net 4.5 and everything is fine there (including cool win 8 window frame).

Is there a solution to enable win 8 style but still support .net 4?

Answer (score 0):

Pardon I've scrapped both .NET 4.0 and XP ages ago :)

[Third party suppliers such as Devcomponents, may have what you are looking for.](https://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/)

But [I'm sure you are already aware of MapApps?](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)
It's made for C# 5.0 and the async-await pattern. What you may do is to use the async-await bridge for 4.0, if it exists. I've done exactly the same thing for .NET 3.5. But the sad thing is that you likely have to do a bit of manual work for porting it back to 4.0 and C#5?

Hope it helps, and hope you get to use C# 5.0 at least.

Cheers,

Stian